# Searching for .class files in an eclipse project's Referenced Library

Tags: java, eclipse, search, .class-file

I'm deconstructing a program, and tracing various .class files from its Referenced Libraries in order to do so. I've tried to use Eclipse's file search but while it can easily find all the .java files given the name it does not seem to be able to find .class files making up the Referenced Libraries' jars the same way. Is there any easy way to trace class files without individually looking through the jars/packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you would prefer class-files over java sources (as in order to understand the program, the latter are much more useful), but you should be able to open find the most appropriate files by either

- pressing `F3` on the desired variable / class in the source code which jumps to its definition
- searching it by name using `CTRL + SHIFT + R` (or `T` to only find types) which lets you find java / class files by name

Comment: I have a plugin that lets me decompile the class files into java source code. I'm pretty sure the class files I'm looking at have no corresponding .java files within the project (ie none of the folders contain ProcessingComponent.java to go along with ProcessingComponent.class in one of the Referenced Libraries jars). Right now I'm looking at a class file that extends another class and implements an interface, and I'm trying to find the corresponding class files for those. I tried using your methods, F3 did nothing for some reason and ctrl+shift+R lets me find corresponding html javadocs

Comment: from whose directory structure I can find the original class file in the corresponding jar library contained within Referenced Libraries. But if I just type Filename.class, it cannot locate it. I'm pretty much a layman at this point, so if I'm saying something stupid/missing something obvious feel free to correct me with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Hm, ok. I don't find any class files in jars either, thats right. I found that `CTRL + ALT + H` (open type in hieararchy) includes class files in search. Probably that helps somehow? Other than that, I know that Java Decompiler (JAD) starts decompilation by hitting `F3`on the desired type.

Comment: Yes that's the sort of thing I was looking for. On an expanded note, is there a way to also search for/extract interface information from jar files? Type hierarchy says it can look for methods, classes, fields and initializers, but when I try locate an interface being implemented it can't come up with anything.

Comment: Does not seem to make a difference for me here: classes as well as interfaces can be found like that.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - no classes in JAR files listed under "Referenced Libraries" (in other words, classes added to the build path via adding an External Class Folder) show up using `CTRL + SHIFT + T`; only those under "JRE System Library" can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Search the classes from the project

```
CTRL + SHIFT + R
```

Search the classes from the referenced libraries and project

```
CTRL + SHIFT + T
```